# handlebars.js : get @key from 1. for-each?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Sorry about the headline, didnt know what else to call this :(

Im new to handlebars.js and im trying to do this:

```
{{#each .}}
    @key 
    {{#each .}}
    @key from the first "each"     <<<< this is the problem   
    @value
    {{/each}}     
{{/each}}
```

How do i get the @key from the first "each" to use in my 2. "each"?

**Solution**

```
{{#each .}}
{{type @key}}
    @key 
        {{#each .}}
        {{ ../@key }}    
        @value
    {{/each}}     
{{/each}}

Handlebars.registerHelper('type', function(value){
this.key = value;
});
```

Comment: Might want to open an issue on https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues - generally you should be able to put ../ in front of a variable to "look up a level", but in the case of @ variables you can't. And since you can't store the data anywhere (like Smarty, where you'd do {assign "name" "Bob"}) it's very.. frustrating.

Comment: The helper i just wrote should work :)

Comment: Sneaky. I'd still say open an issue on github though - that way we don't need to 'hack' to get it to work the way that it seems it should.

Comment: It is on github, and has been for almost a year :(